# Scheduling Algorithm - Minimum start time

Tags: algorithm, greedy

Supposedly there exists a greedy algorithm for solving the following problem, however I have been unable to find one (or design one).

You are running the interplanetary shuttle service from the planet Maximegalon IV to the planet Huygen’s
Landing. Your spaceship has m seats and the trip takes t units of time one way. (The trip back takes t
units of time as well, but you never bring passengers in that direction.) You know in advance when your
passengers arrive at Maximegalon IV. Your task is to finish as fast as possible, i.e., minimize the arrival time
of the last passenger.

Input

The first line contains three integers, the number of passenger n, the capacity of your spaceship m, and the
one-way trip time t (in Galactic hours). Then follow n lines, one for each passenger, giving their earliest
departure time (in Galactic hours) from Maximegalon IV.

Output
The earliest time at which all passengers have arrived at Huygen’s Landing.

Can anybody help? Maybe with a link or a hint...

Thanks in advance

Comment: Maybe have you tried anything?

Comment: Ideally, the last departing passenger would occupy the last seat of the last trip, and leave as early as possible. Try working from there.